# TreeTableView multiple column header rows

Tags: javafx, treetableview

I am having one TreeTableView and that table has one Column Header. Table has some data rows and those rows has some plus side at left side and if I clicked on that plus sign and it will fetch the data from the another table and that table also has Column Header Row.

**Can I have multiple column header rows in TreeTableView?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: Can I have multiple column header rows in TreeTableView?

Comment: You mean somthing like this ? http://i.imgur.com/obvY4QE.png

Comment: Nope @Kwoinkwoin. It is the merging. But I want something like. A B C columns , A1 B1 C1 as items and again X Y Z as columns in one table.

Comment: No, in one TableView/TreeTableView this is not possible. Only one TableColumn "row" is possible. You would need to add another table below to realize what you desire.